Convert multi column table into a 4 column table where the first 3 columns are keys/dates for the values
I have a table like the below



no header
no header
no header




id_header
id#1
id#2


address_header
address#1
address#2


date#1
value#1
value#1


date#2
value#2
value#2



I would like to reshape it for use in Power BI so that it reads



date
id
address
values




date#1
id#1
address#1
value#1


date#2
id#1
address#1
value#2


date#1
id#2
address#2
value#1


date#2
id#2
address#2
value#2



Basically repeating the date and id and address on every row and putting all the values in a value column

This feels similar to this problem on StackOverflow the answers there might get it done, or at least get you started.

Starting here:

Use Transform>Transpose to get this:

Use Transform>'Use First Row as Headers' to get this:

Types will be assigned automatically.
Select the two date columns and use Transform>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot Only Selected Columns to get this:

Reorder and rename the columns as required:

